# DLL (Delphi) with ADO (connection and query) not work in Java (using jna)

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I have a dll (Delphi) that contains a ADOConnection and ADOQuery, but when running the called DLL in java (using JNA) appear some error information to the console (below):

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> Internal Error (0xeedfade), pid=4400, tid=3840
>
> JRE version: 6.0_25-b06  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (20.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   C:\Users\Mmn1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FLMOPDL\hs_err_pid4400.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

What bug is this?
(I realized that it is only happens if I have a form or as a component in the case ADOConnection ADOQuery and if I remove these components and perform a simple function, it works normally).

Edit:

A similar exemple bellow:

```
library TESTLIB;
{$DEFINE TESTLIB}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  TestInt in 'TestInt.pas',
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  sharemem,
  Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB;

{$R *.res}

function MyReturn(x: Integer; Test: PTest): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  ado: TADOQuery;
begin
    Result := True;
    //ado := TADOQuery.Create(nil); <- With this i got a error!
end;

exports MyReturn;

begin
end.
```

interface in Java

```
public interface TestInt extends StdCallLibrary {
    TestInt INSTANCE = (TestInt)Native.loadLibrary("C:/test/Win32/Debug/TESTLIB", TestInt.class);

    class Test extends Structure {
        public String vResult;

        public Test() { }
        public Test(int x, Pointer p) {
            super(p);
            read();
        }
        protected List getFieldOrder() { return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "vResult" }); }
    }

    Boolean MyReturn(int x, Test test);
}
```

conclusion: when I use a component, this error raise. Thanks for help.

Comment: You'll need some more information to get to the bottom of that. `0xeedfade` is the SEH exception code for a Delphi language extension. Why you DLL has thrown the exception is very hard to say. Only you have the code. I suggest that you run it under the debugger to work out what is going on.

Comment: the same dll running through an executable functions normally done in Delphi. I've been searching about (over two days) and found no information about it.

Comment: You need to debug it. You need more information.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem might be, as you failed to include the Java code that's calling your DLL code (including the way you declared it in Java in the first place). Can you [edit] to do so? Without it, there's no information here we can use to answer it, and it will probably be closed as 'too localized". Thanks.

Comment: Why the `sharemem`? Maybe it's causing the problem?

Comment: No. I did tests using ShareMem (borlndmm.dll) because I thought that could be a problem of memory allocation, but it is not.

Comment: Well, then maybe a `CoInitialize` is needed in your `MyReturn` function.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to guess. Who is calling `CoInitialize`? Is anyone doing that? Your ADO query object presumably needs it.

Comment: @kobik or rather in DllMain - why call it twice ?

Comment: @Arioch'The, Usually the calling thread will be responsible for calling `CoInitialize` and not the DLL... But I don't think it's relevant at this point, since the OP did not say if it solves the initial problem or not.

Comment: @Arioch No, never call CoInitialize from DllMain. The documentation says so explicitly. In fact never call it from a DLL because the app has to be in charge of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-edited:

I got the solution. The problem was "how to" DLL had been made. Below the solution and I hope it helps more people:

TESTLIB (Delphi)

```
library TESTLIB;
{$DEFINE TESTLIB}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  TestInt in 'TestInt.pas', //here's my unit (interface)
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  ADODB,
  Vcl.Forms;

  {$R *.res}


function MyReturn(Test: PTest): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  ado: TADOQuery;
  con: TADOConnection;
begin
    con := TADOConnection.Create(Application);
    ado := TADOQuery.Create(Application);

    con.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=aaa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aa;Initial Catalog=aa;Data Source=127.0.0.1';
    con.LoginPrompt := False;
    con.Open();

    if con.Connected = True then
        ShowMessage('connected ok')
    else
        ShowMessage('not connected');

    ado.Active := False;
    ado.Connection := con;
    ado.SQL.Clear;
    ado.SQL.Add('select lalala from table where codlala = 1');
    try
        ado.Open();
        Test^.vResult := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ado.FieldByName('fantasia').AsString));
        Result := True;
    except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage('error to open the query' + #13 + 'Error: ' + E.Message);
          Result := False;
        end;
    end;
end;

exports MyReturn;

begin
end.
```

Interface Ole32 (java)

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Ole32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    Ole32 INSTANCE = (Ole32) Native.loadLibrary("Ole32", Ole32.class);

    public HRESULT CoInitialize(Pointer p);

    public HRESULT CoUninitialize();

}
```

Special thanks to kobik and technomage about `CoInitialize`

links that helped me:

[TADOConnection failing in application initialization section of Delphi ISAPI App:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264136/tadoconnection-failing-in-application-initialization-section-of-delphi-isapi-app)

[Add CoInitializing constants and improve documentation](https://github.com/twall/jna/issues/69)

[Using COM from Java via JNA](http://blog.abstractinvoke.com/2011/07/using-com-from-java-via-jna/)

Comment: You should not call CoInitialize inside a DLL, it is meant to be initialized form the calling process. Read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/05/12/130541.aspx

Comment: JNA makes `CoInitialize` available in `platform.jar`.  You should call that one from the application, rather than the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

According to the message, the problem is

> outside the Java Virtual Machine

in this case, it's probably in the Delphi code.

You might want to contact the developer(s) of the Delphi code and see if they can assist in troubleshooting the issue, or browse the code yourself to see what's going on. The `hs_err_pid4400.log` file will contain valuable information for them.

Either way, without Delphi source code it's hard to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: It's for sure in the Delphi code. It's an unhandled Delphi language exception. That's what `0xeedfade` indicates.

Comment: strange because as I said above, the same dll running on an application made ​​in delphi functions normally. This problem occurs when I try to use the same dll in java.

Comment: Carefully compare the way the Delphi application calls the code from the DLL to the way the Java application calls the same code. Any differences might explain the cause of the error.

Comment: Application might easily call `CoInitialize` for its own needs, for example if it had ADO or Office components on its forms