# JNA calling CoInitialize when loading a dll

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I've got a dll written in Pascal. I've determined that I need to run CoInitialize in the Java code, but I just can't figure out how.

I found another Stack Overflow thread which should have helped here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763993](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763993/) but I couldn't understand how it actually worked.

My current code that I have now is here:

```
public interface CSQLLib extends StdCallLibrary {

    CSQLLib INSTANCE = (CSQLLib) Native.loadLibrary("DatabaseLibrary", CSQLLib.class);

    public HRESULT CoInitialize(Pointer p);

    public HRESULT CoUninitialize();

    public String doSQLQuery(String input);
    public void DllMessage();
}
```

Comment: There is no other documentation that I can find for this. It's really annoying.

Comment: Ok, fine. I'm just going to call CoInitialize in my Delphi code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of calling `CoInitializeEx` from Java code using JNA:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(null,Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  }
}
```

Note that use of `CoInitializeEx` is recommended by both the [JNA docs](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Ole32.html#CoInitialize-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPVOID-) and the [Windows SDK docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) instead of `CoInitialize`. `CoInitialize(null)` is equivalent to `CoInitializeEx(null,Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)`, but the JNA docs recommend using `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` instead in Java apps (indeed, they call it "the only sane choice") – however, despite what they say, some COM interfaces only work correctly with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`, so it really depends on the COM objects you are using. Whichever you choose, `CoInitializeEx` is better because it makes it obvious (rather than implicit) which COM threading mode you are using.

Note the solution you mentioned in your comment, calling `CoInitialize` from within your DLL written in Delphi, is not a good practice. COM should be initialised in the application not in a DLL. If you ever attempt to reuse your DLL in some other application (which is already calling `CoInitialize`/`CoInitializeEx`), it is likely your call to it will fail with `S_FALSE` or `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE` because the application will have already initialised it.

Comment: In the end I hacked together some awful code that just initialised the DLL every time I needed to use it. I'm not proud of it, but it worked well enough to get the job done.