# Error when calling winAPI native code (ADsGetObject) from JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm trying to learn how to work with windows native code from Java. For this I use the JNA library. I'm just starting to learn how to work with this library and ran into this problem. The [ADsGetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsgetobject) function call fails. Perhaps I did not fully understand how to convert data types and do not use them correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid.REFIID;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HRESULT;

public class GetUserAttribute {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getUser("CN=Scaner,OU=Services,DC=my,DC=domain");
    }

    public interface Activeds extends StdCallLibrary {
        Activeds INSTANCE = (Activeds) Native.load("Activeds", Activeds.class);
        HRESULT ADsGetObject(WString lpszPathName, REFIID riid, PointerByReference ppObject);
    }

    public static void getUser(String dn) {
        WString userDN = new WString(dn);
        REFIID riid = new REFIID();
        PointerByReference ppObject = new PointerByReference();
        HRESULT hr = Activeds.INSTANCE.ADsGetObject(userDN,riid,ppObject);
        System.out.println(hr);
    }
```

When executed, hr is 0x80004005 (Unspecified error). I would be grateful for any hints on what I'm doing wrong and maybe for an example of a working code.

Here is the code on VBS that works correctly. Would like to "translate" it into Java code:

```
Dim strUserDN = "CN=Scaner,OU=Services,DC=my,DC=domain" 
set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)
Wscript.echo objUser.cn
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning a guid value to `riid`, so you are effectively setting it to `IID_NULL` (`{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`).  You need to set it to `IID_IADs` (`{FD8256D0-FD15-11CE-ABC4-02608C9E7553}`) instead.

That will cause `ADsGetObject()` (if successful) to set `ppObject` to point at an [`IADs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iads) interface. Make sure that you call [`IUnknown.Release()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-release) on `ppObject` when you are done using that interface.

Also, the thread that is calling `ADsGetObject()` must call [`CoInitialize/Ex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) beforehand. And call [`CoUninitialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize) when it is done using the COM library.  You can use `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32` for that.

See the examples at [How to use CoInitializeEx method in com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32/CoInitializeEx). Also see [JNA calling CoInitialize when loading a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872146/)

Comment: It's really best *not* to call `CoUninitialize`, especially in a runtime environment where object destruction happens at a non-deterministic point in time.